# PHP parse part of script in separate server

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, fastcgi, lighttpd

I'm looking forward to use a structure something like the one proposed by Amazon (http://media.amazonwebservices.com/architecturecenter/AWS_ac_ra_web_01.pdf). I have an application that have several low demanding parsing requirements. However, there are some analysis functions that requires large amount of memory. What I would like to know is how can I make this requests be parsed by this application server?

My servers are currently running PHP 5.4.15 in Fast-CGI and lightTPD 1.4.32. Would you recommend this structure (with separate application server for the high memory process), or a more simple infrastructure?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: You could create an API/Webservice interface to transfer data/tasks between servers.

Comment: split your script up into multiple parts (services) and have the services interact with each other as necessary to complete your tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't parse "part" of a PHP script on a separate server, that's a fundamental disconnect on the way PHP works. 
If you are looking to do load balancing, and you know what scripts are doing the heavy lifting, then you could certainly use a separate server for memory intensive processing- analyze the request when it comes into your balancing server, and depending on the required function send it to either the application server or the analysis server. Thad would require 3 boxes.
A simpler option would be to forward requests from the client that require analysis but do all non-analysis operations directly on the balancing box.

Comment: sorry, I expressed my self wrong. I know I can't parse "part" of a php script. Let me see if I understood, what you are saying is to, if heavy_script.php is called, redirect this call to a separate server? Can I achieve that with fast-cgi server? Don't know if that is possible, but in lighttpd put the file name and redirect to an internal server? Thank you for the reply!